# Приложение не запускается в Docker

Tags: postgresql, golang, docker

Есть Dockerfile с таким содержимым:

```
FROM golang:alpine AS builder

ADD . /src
RUN cd /src && go build -o main.bin cmd/main.go

# Final step
FROM alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /src/main.bin /app/

ENTRYPOINT ./main.bin
```

И compose-docker.yaml с таким:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  your-app:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
      target: builder
    expose:
      - 80
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/app

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ****
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: always

  migrations:
    image: ifraixedes/goose:latest
#    environment:
#      DB_DSN: "host=localhost:5432 user=postgres dbname=db password=**** sslmode=disable"
    entrypoint: sh
    command:
      - -c
      - |-
        goose postgres 'host=localhost:5432 user=postgres dbname=db password=**** sslmode=disable' status
        while [ $$? -ne 0 ]; do goose postgres 'host=localhost:5432 user=admin dbname=db password=1234 sslmode=disable' status; done
        goose -dir "/migrations" postgres "host=localhost:5432 user=postgres dbname=InnowiseTask password=8403 sslmode=disable" up
    volumes:
      - ./migrations:/migrations
volumes:
  db:
```

В итоге запускается postgres и migration, а приложение нет[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В логах пусто

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно, что вы указали в `docker-compose.yaml` то и проиcходит.

Вы указали `target: builder`. Что у вас написано в `Dockerfile` об этом этапе:

```
FROM golang:alpine AS builder

ADD . /src
RUN cd /src && go build -o main.bin cmd/main.go
```

На этапе `builder` собирается докер без указанной стартовой точки. Следовательно, берётся `ENTRYPOINT` из `golang.alpine`. То есть `/bin/sh`. Шелл запускается, обнаруживает, что он неинтерактивный, и сразу же завершается.

Вам нужно либо убрать target из `docker-compose.yaml` (в принципе, вам вполне достаточно указать `build: .`) либо нужно поименовать второй этап и указать это имя в `target`:

```
# Final step
FROM alpine as runner

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /src/main.bin /app/

ENTRYPOINT ./main.bin
```

```
  your-app:
    build: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
      target: runner
```

Comment: Спасибо это помогло, но теперь ошибка в том что не существует, такой базы данных. Хотя вроде миграцию я написал, не знаете в чем может быть ошибка? Уже неделю мучаюсь с этим докером...

Comment: Никогда goose не пользовалься но из общих соображений... У вас в докере goose написана строка базы данных `localhost:5432`. Это странно, ведь `localhost` находится внутри докера `migrations`. docker-compose поднимает внутреннюю сеть, в которой сервер базы данных называется `postgres` (по имени сервиса), поэтому должно быть `host=postgres:5432`. Далее, `migrations` должен запускаться после `postgres`, поэтому в него нужно добавить `depends_on` `- postgres`, а в `your-app` `depends_on` `- migrations`. Ну и в вашем приложении нужно обращаться к базе данных на хосте postgres

Comment: Я чутка погуглил и нашел статью https://geshan.com.np/blog/2021/12/docker-postgres/ . В ней есть как подключить инициализационный скрипт. Ещё я заметил, что у вас `volumes - db` не указан `driver`

Comment: В логах в докере такая ошибка

 error: unknown command "postgres"

хотя в документации все также, такой же скрипт

Comment: @DenisIgorevich сделайте отдельный вопрос и приложите к нему минимально воспроизводимый пример - sql скрипты в миграциях, go приложение которое подключается к базе. Без таких подробностей поиски решения бессмысленны

Answer (score 0):

В общем, если кто-то вдруг столкнется с такой же проблемой.

Вот новый docker-compose. Теперь миграцию делаю, можно сказать, вручную, с помощью создания таблицы через SQL запрос.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "your_db_name"
      POSTGRES_USER: "your_db_user"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "your_db_password"
      PGDATA: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
     #- db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./db/init.sql.:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
  app:
    image: appimage
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
      target: runner
    expose:
      - 8081
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/app
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

Вот здесь команда для миграции. И в файле init.sql находится скрипт который создает мою таблицу.

```
 volumes:
      - ./db/init.sql.:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
```

Вот сам скрипт.

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id UUID NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT id_user PRIMARY KEY(id),
    firstname CHARACTER VARYING(30),
    lastname CHARACTER VARYING(30),
    email CHARACTER VARYING(40) UNIQUE,
    age integer,
    created timestamp
);
```

Собственно говоря проблема была из-за закомментированной строки,

```
#- db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

так как она инициализировала пустую бд, из-за чего скрипт создания таблицы просто пропускался.

Это не совсем ответ но мой вопрос, но все же может быть он кому-то поможет.